# Extract Array of Coordinates from Line (C++ OpenCV)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, line, coordinates

Using C++ / OpenCV I've drawn a line on an image using `cv::line` and now I'm trying to extract an array of its coordinates. I've tried assigning the line to `cv::Mat` but I get an error stating I cannot convert from void to `cv::Mat`. Is there a simple way to obtain these coordinates?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean an array of its cordinates? Do you need four corners of line?? What type do you need for the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least a couple of options. Assuming that you know the two endpoints  `A` and `B`of the line:

1) Draw the line with `line(...)` on an zero initialized mask of the same size of your image, and retrieve the points on the line (which will be the only white points on the mask) with `findNonZero(...)`.

2) Use `LineIterator` to retrieve the points, without the need of drawing them nor creating a mask.

You need to store your points in a `vector<Point>`.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat3b image(100,100); // Image will contain your original rgb image

    // Line endpoints:
    Point A(10,20);
    Point B(50,80);


    // Method: 1) Create a mask
    Mat1b mask(image.size(), uchar(0));
    line(mask, A, B, Scalar(255));

    vector<Point> points1;
    findNonZero(mask, points1);

    // Method: 2) Use LineIterator
    LineIterator lit(image, A, B);

    vector<Point> points2;
    points2.reserve(lit.count);
    for (int i = 0; i < lit.count; ++i, ++lit)
    {
        points2.push_back(lit.pos());
    }

    // points1 and points2 contains the same points now!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very useful and thorough answer - very much appreciated! Accepting this answer as it contains multiple options for other users if their circumstances are slightly different to mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can see this answer. I presume this is what your question needs, [Finding points in a line](http://answers.opencv.org/question/66758/how-would-you-get-all-the-points-on-a-line/?answer=66779#post-id-66779).

Opencv has [Line Iterator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) function. Go through the documentation!

Here is a sample usage!

```
LineIterator it(img, pt1, pt2, 8);
for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
{
    Point pt= it.pos(); 
   //Draw Some stuff using that Point pt
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this post is now much more useful. (and will survive if the link rots) :)