# coordinate of drawn line opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

i am trying to get all the x and y coordinate of a drawn line. i have draw the line using the following code.

```
Core.line(line, new Point(x, y), new Point(j+bounding_rect.width, k), new Scalar(255,0,0),1);
```

i have been looking on the internet and cannot get what i want. My real aim is to get the point of intersection of the line a contour. i have been able to get all the coordinate for the contour. If there is a better method than comparing the points, please help.
Thank in advance

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808048/5008845) for a couple of options. It's C++ but should be available the equivalent in the OpenCV Java wrapper. You can either draw the line and the contour on two empty images, and _AND_ them. You can then easily find if there is an intersection, as there will be on (or more) white pixels. Or, better, you can use a `LineIterator` and check for each pixel on the line if it belong also to the contour

Comment: i was trying it, but LineIterator is missing

Comment: Then you can take some other implementation of the line drawing algorithm, E.g. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Java

Comment: when looking at those algorithm, i get an idea. first i look for the gradient of the line and then i tried every coordinate of the contour in the gradient equation. it should return 2 result.

Comment: Thank for your help @Miki